# How to find all the hexadecimal numbers in between 2 numbers

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I want to write a little function that would determine all the hexadecimal numbers present between 2 numbers.

`input.txt`:

```
2E25:2E30
```

Desired output:

```
2E25
2E26
2E27
2E28
2E29
2E2A
2E2B
2E2C
2E2D
2E2E
2E2F
2E30
```

I need to achieve this in a shell script using KSH and OS is Solaris 9.

Comment: I could do it in bash… but I'm not familiar with KSH. It might be compatible enough.

Comment: `for i in $(seq $((0x2E25)) $((0x2E30))); do printf '%x\n' $i | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'; done`

Comment: @Sparhawk this should be an Answer.

Comment: @RonJohn I can't remember now, but I probably didn't write it up because it was bash, not ksh, and I wasn't sure of the differences.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using only shell built-ins:

```
$ IFS=: read start end < input.txt
$ for (( x=16#$start; x<=16#$end; x++ )); do printf "%X\n" $x; done
2E25
2E26
2E27
2E28
2E29
2E2A
2E2B
2E2C
2E2D
2E2E
2E2F
2E30
```

First, we read the start and end parameters from disk. Then, we loop, interpreting the values as hexadecimal numbers (see the `Arithmetic Evaluation` section of the `ksh` manpage for discussion of the `[base#]n` construct), then printing each entry, formatting it as hexadecimal.

Please note, I don't use `ksh` regularly, there is likely a better approach to this problem.